# What are hundreds of kernel extensions from com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.UpdateBrainService for on my MacBook?

Tags: mobile-device-management, kernel-extensions

The following situation this morning on my MacBook Pro 16-inch 2021 running Monterey 12.5.1: hundreds of kernel extensions were waiting for allowing to be installed. Am running BlockBlock, set to ask for permission to install kernel extensions.

[image]

All of them were from com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.UpdateBrainService. Did do a search on that, the few results pertained iPhone updates. Which begs my question: what are all these kernel extensions for on my laptop?

Comment: Do you have automatic updates enabled? My understanding, that service is used to assemble updates after download and before installing. It is for macOS, just looks like iPhone update. Hopefully someone can give a decent answer.

Comment: @Gilby yes, automatic updates are enabled.

Comment: I 'think' what you are seeing is part of the update process when automatic updates are enabled.  For now, don't worry - wait for a more definite answer.